# Target Cocoa Touch Framework not generated

Tags: ios8, xcode6, cocoa-touch

I am trying to create the Cocoa Touch Framework but when I build the framework it says "Build Succeeded" but it is not able to locate .framework in the Finder. I tried creating a new project too adding only one file and even then I experience the similar behavior of XCode. Am I missing something to generate .framework. Thanks in Advance.